# apt-get install fails when building a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile    
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install git
```

But it fails with an error

```
ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install git' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was being stupid. I just needed to add `-y` option to `apt-get install`.

```
# Dockerfile    
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git
```